# No Set State or Async but still "Can't perform state update on unmounted component" error

Tags: reactjs, components

I have nearly given up with this. I can't get my component to work no matter what I do. I have read all the error posts here and on Google but still nothing. I get the error

`Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

Here is my full code...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react;

// page title bar
import PageTitleBar from 'Components/PageTitleBar/PageTitleBar';

import {
    NewsFeedWidget
} from "Components/Widgets";

// widgets data
import {
    newsData,
} from './data';

export default class EcommerceDashboard extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ecom-dashboard-wrapper">
                <div className="content_container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-4 w-xs-full">
                            <NewsFeedWidget data={newsData} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and NewsFeed.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

const NewsFeedWidget = ({ data }) => (
    <div className="cardheader_container">
        <div className="notification_container">
            {data && data.map((d, key) => (
                <div className="a_notification" key={key}>
                    <div className="not_header">
                        <div className="not_content">
                            <h5>{d.title}</h5>
                            <p>{d.subtitle}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default NewsFeedWidget;
```

Obviously I am new at React so please explain how and what issue I am having. It's gonna be something dumb I bet but this is how i'll learn.

ty

Comment: I also found this error maybe related: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Comment: post your `data` file also. You are probably missed exporting the content from `data` file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you upload the code for PageTitleBar too ?

Comment: I think you can ignore that. The page blinks as if it's about to load and then goes white with that error. When I delete "NewsFeedWidget" it works so must be localised in that component. Funnily when I delete everything from NewsFeedWidget it still doesn't work. :S